# Hosts redirection not working properly

Tags: windows, networking, hosts

Simply put, I want to redirect uk.wikipedia.org to en.wikipedia.org.

I put this in the hosts file on windows, saved it, and flushed the DNS cache:

```
91.198.174.225      uk.wikipedia.org
```

But when I try to visit uk.wikipedia.org, I get a timeout error, and it's not redirecting me to en.wikipedia.org.

Help?

It's not a web browser cache issue, as I've tried with multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `dig uk.wikipedia.org` you also get `91.198.174.225`, same as `dig en.wikipedia.org`. So probably all pages are actually accessed through the same IP. The webserver figures out which page to serve to you depending on the `Host` field in the HTTP-Request headers. (See apache's [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) for example).
To change which page is requested you'd have to modify the Http headers. This is probably best done with a browser plugin of some sort.

**Edit:** There doesn't seem to be a premade tool for changing http headers only on certain domains. But maybe you could use this: [Firefox Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/redirector/)?